# In AJAX, responseText from XMLHttpRequest is always with tag removed, why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Every time the server send the xml string to the client XMLHttpRequest object, when I post the text inside the div tags, it is all without tag, while I want the xml tag for me to parse.

Now I only got all the element values concatenated together as a single string, getting substring from it is quite troublesome. Is it any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because when the browser sees an xml string like

`<someElement>blah</someElement>`

it interprets **<** and **>** as being part of the html document.  You probably need to escape the response text, replacing all **<** with `&lt;` and **>** with `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourDiv.innerText = yourXML;` rather than `yourDiv.innerHTML = yourXML;`.